# Include subdirectories and exclude their content with fileTree

Tags: gradle, groovy

```
d:\build
├── file1.txt
├── folder1
|  └── anotherfile.txt
├── folder2
|  └── subsubfolder
└── folderN
```

When I do

```
println fileTree("d:\build").collect()
```

I get

```
[d:\build\file1.txt, d:\build\folder1\anotherfile.txt]
```

What I want is only the files and folders in this directory

```
[d:\build\file1.txt, d:\build\folder1, d:\build\folder2, d:\build\folderN]
```

The reason I want to use `fileTree` with `.collect()` is because it's [lazy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/lazy_configuration.html#working_with_files_in_lazy_properties) and does not cause this [null pointer exception](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/pass-a-directory-which-is-not-created-yet-in-configuration-step/38471) at configuration stage.

How do I do that?

Comment: why do you need your directory at the moment it has not yet been created? I think you should rather make your task dependent on other tasks, to make sure the directory exists by that moment -> hence "lazyness"

Comment: Try putting the code causing a null pointer exception into a closure. Later, call this closure and at that time the code is evaluated.

Comment: @injecteer Even if I make the task2 dependOn task1, it's still an error if I try to put files in a property of task2 using anything other than fileTree. I have solved it using fileTree anyway.

Comment: @Catalin If I changed that to closure, I would have to modify the implementation of that property to evaluate the closure. Not something I wanted.

Comment: you could shift your file traversion to excecution phase with `doFirst{}` / `doLast{}`

Comment: @injecteer The way I thought I did it was incorrect. What you suggested is the correct way. instead of setting property in configuration phase, I can just set it in `doFirst{}`.

Comment: @injecteer using `doFirst{}` to fill in a property does not work. Property must be filled in at configuration phase. It gives error if I don't. I *can* give a fake value in configuration phase though which will be overridden by the value in `doFirst{}`

Comment: you can still hide the property implementation by using a get method, like getSomeProperty(). inside that method you call the closure and outside you access it just by using the property name: def var = someProperty

Comment: @Catalin It feels like you are telling something correct. I don't quite get it though. How would I pass a closure to `fileList` (with no source code access) in this https://discuss.gradle.org/t/pass-a-directory-which-is-not-created-yet-in-configuration-step/38471 ?

Comment: I smell that you are trying to solve a rather simple problem in a complicated way. Describe the original problem instead of techincal details of your failure

Comment: @injecteer I think this question is still valid on it's own so I wrote another one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65238950/how-to-set-a-property-of-a-task-lazily