# How to set a property of a task lazily?

Tags: gradle, groovy

```
task task1(type: ProduceFilesTaskType) {
   outDir = file("$projectDir/some/files")
}

task task2(type: ConsumeFilesTaskType) {
   fileList = file("$doSomething.outDir/somefolders/").listFiles().toList() // null pointer exception
}
```

I don't have the source of `ConsumeFilesTaskType` and it requires a `List<File> fileList` which is produced by `task1`.

Now because these files don't exist in configuration phase, gradle fails at configuration stage with error `Cannot invoke method toList() on null object` because there are no files.

I can probably do this

```
task task2(type: ConsumeFilesTaskType) {
   fileList = new ArrayList<File>() // don't fail
   doFirst {
      fileList = file("$doSomething.outDir/somefolders/").listFiles().toList() // actual list of files
   }
}
```

Is this the standard way or is there a better way to set/evaluate a property lazily?

Comment: doFirst, doLast is a standard way

Comment: @daggett alongwith initialization of the property with an empty instance?

Comment: The null pointer exception is not because fileList is null, but file("$doSomething.outDir/somefolders/") returns null. I don't think you need the  fileList = new ArrayList<File>() unless something else is going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot constructs in Gradle that are lazily evaluated. In a way Gradle is built on top of the idea of lazy evaluation. That being said, it also depends on how your ConsumeFilesTaskType is implemented. Nothing can help if the task itself is not **using** the fileList parameter lazily.

If the fileList is typed as `Iterable<File>`, or the Gradle provided type `FileCollection`, you can assign it to project.fileTree() at configuration phase:

```groovy
Iterable<File> fileList;

task myTask {
    fileList = project.fileTree("build") // build might not exist at this moment
    
    doLast {
        fileList.forEach { println it.name }
    }
}
```

There is a similar method `project.files()` that creates a ConfigurableFileCollection object. The `project.files()` documentation does a better job at explaining what it means by "lazy" and "live". `project.fileTree()` returns a ConfigurableFileTree that is also lazy and live. The difference is that ConfigurableFileTree interprets the files added as roots. When iterating, ConfigurableFileTree recursively traverses these root directories to collect actual files for the caller.